# How to fail in struct creation?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a `struct` that should get its values from an `ini` file. I have a `load` method that loads the file and returns an `Option<Settings>`.

What is the best way to fail and abort the struct creation? Should I return None or call `fail!`? Returning None seems to be the idiomatic way to handle this but `fail!` allows me to display a message.

How can I fail and send a message to my user, more or less what I'd do with exceptions in C++/Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/type.Result.html) type from the standard library. It lets you return either an `Ok` with the value or an `Err` with an error message (or whatever type of value you want). Then the caller of `load()` can handle printing out the error message to the user.

Here's an example:

```
enum DivError {
    DivisionByZero
}

fn divide(a: int, b: int) -> Result<int, DivError> {
    if b == 0 {
        Err(DivisionByZero)
    } else {
        Ok(a / b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let answer = divide(1, 0);

    match answer {
        Ok(result) => println!("The answer is {}.", result),
        Err(DivisionByZero) => println!("Oops! You divided by zero.")
    }
}
```

Comment: This changes everything.